# Redux fetch actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, fetch

I create app with react and redux and I need to fetch data. Is there any way to reuse function getData() and reducer. My actions looks like this

```
importing constants

const getDataRequested = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_DATA_REQUESTED
  };
}

const getDataDone = data => {
  return {
    type: GET_DATA_DONE,
    payload: data
  };
}

const getDataFailed = () => {
  return {
    type: GET_DATA_FAILED
  };
}

export const getData = () => dispatch => {

  dispatch(getDataRequested());

  fetch('url')
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(data => {
      dispatch(getDataDone(data));
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch(getDataFailed(error));
    })
}
```

and reducer

```
importing constants

const initialState = {
  isLoading: false,
  isError: false,
  data: [],
}
export default (state=initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_DATA_REQUESTED:
      return { ...state, isLoading: true };
    case GET_DATA_DONE:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, data: action.payload };
    case GET_DATA_FAILED:
      return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true}
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

Every time I fetch something with different url I create new action and new reducer. Is it ok or there is some way to reuse it?

Comment: You don't need to create a new reducer every time, but you must create new actions. That is the way redux works.

Comment: You mean i have to add more case in reducer and new actions for each fetch (e.g. GET_DATA_REQUESTED, GET_DATA_DONE, GET_DATA_FAILED, GET_DATA2_REQUESTED, GET_DATA2_DONE, GET_DATA2_FAILED)

Comment: Oh, I believe I misunderstood your question. I will add an answer, and you can check if it is what you need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass a url parameter to your thunk. So, you could have something like this:

```
export const getData = (url) => dispatch => {

    dispatch(getDataRequested());

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            dispatch(getDataDone(data));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(getDataFailed(error));
        })
}
```

This way you can dispatch as many actions as you want changing only the url parameter, like this: getData('/user'), getData('/products').

You can also customize the way you store the state into redux by passing more parameters to the thunk. So it could be something like this:

```
const getDataDone = data => {
    return {
        type: GET_DATA_DONE,
        payload: data
    };
}

export const getData = (url, stateName) => dispatch => {
    dispatch(getDataRequested());

    fetch(url)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            dispatch(getDataDone({ stateName: data }));
        })
        .catch(error => {
            dispatch(getDataFailed(error));
        })
}
```

And the reducer could be something like this:

```
const initialState = {
    isLoading: false,
    isError: false,
    data: {},
}
export default (state=initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_DATA_REQUESTED:
            return { ...state, isLoading: true };
        case GET_DATA_DONE:
            return { ...state, isLoading: false, [action.payload.stateName]: action.payload.data };
        case GET_DATA_FAILED:
            return { ...state, isLoading: false, isError: true}
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

That way you can dispatch actions like getData('/user', 'user') or getData('/products', 'products') and have a state like this:

```
{
    user: {
        // your users data
    },
    products: {
        // your products data
    }
}
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks a lot! I have one more question. What should I do if I want to have private isLoading and IsError for both users and products?

Comment: The only way I can think of is using objects to hold the loading and error data. So it could be like: { loading: { user: true, products: false }, isError: { user: false, products: true } }.

Comment: Good idea. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all actions in one function like

```
function getData() {
  return {
    types: [GET_DATA_REQUESTED, GET_DATA_DONE, GET_DATA_FAILED],
    callApi: fetch('/')
  }
}
```

but you need to connect your component and pass the function as props

```
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
   return {
    getData: () => dispatch(getData())
   };
}

connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(YourComponent)
```

now you can use the function in your component and it will return a promise.
check out the Docs for redux: https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux

Comment: I don't get it. Where is redux thunk here and how can i reuse it? Could you show me example with two different fetch url?

Comment: your should apply the thunk when you created your store`const store = createStore(appReducer, composeEnhancers(applyMiddleware(thunk, apiMW)));` you can pass the url to the function or create another function for another request

Comment: Could you give me some link to github where getData combine actions are implemented?